# How to install iOS image (dmg file) from Dev Center?

Tags: itunes, ios

I downloaded an iPhone iOS dmg file from the iOS Dev Center, but don't know how to install it.

How do I load it on to my device?

I'm using iTunes 11 on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple to do in Windows:

1. Download the beta `.dmg`.
2. Open it in a file compression/extraction program (I used [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)).
3. Locate and extract the `.ipsw` file. In 7.1 beta 3 this two levels deep in the `2.hfs\` file.
   [image: Locating the iOS 7 beta 3 ipsw file using 7-Zip]
4. In iTunes, goto the **Summary** screen for your iPhone. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click **Restore iPhone...**.
5. Select the `.ipsw` file and proceed with the update.
   [image: Restore dialog with iTunes in the background]

Answer (score 2):

Files and applications in the iOS Dev Center are tools for developers working on iOS application development. As an OS X system is required to run Xcode and to install test apps on an iPhone, any supporting tools require OS X as well. You can't install them directly on iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Xcode (free downloadable from AppStore). In the Xcode you go to Window>Organizer, there to Devices and than drag the app from the dmg file to the device.

Xcode may prompt you to turn the device into the development mode for that. This is only to let Xcode install apps.